# Trying to split a string in C++ but keep getting error R6010

Tags: c++

```
void piglatin(string str)
{
    string temp = str; //copies the string passed to the function into temp.
    temp = temp + str.at(0); //adds the first character of the word to the end of the word.
    temp = temp.erase(0, 1); //deletes the first character from the temp string.
    temp = temp + "AY"; //adds "AY" to the temp string
    cout << temp << " "; //prints out the word followed by a space.
}

string userIn("I NEED THIS IN PIG LATIN");
    istringstream iss(userIn);

   do
   { 
       string sub;
       iss >> sub;
       piglatin(sub);
   } while (iss);
```

so i am trying to use this method to split a string in C++ but I keep on getting an error but the program does what i want it to do. I just need to get rid of the error R6010.

Comment: Could you please post the whole output you are getting?

Comment: here are the directives i have included in my program. # include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <sstream>

Comment: Here is the complete error.
First-chance exception at 0x7609C42D in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0036F300.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is *mostly* okay, it's just that you're checking for end-of-file (or end-of-string in this case) wrongly and that's causing an empty string to be sent to `piglatin()`, resulting in the `str.at(0)` exception.

You can fix that (including making the code a complete workable program) with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void piglatin(string str) {
    string temp = str;
    temp = temp + str.at(0);
    temp = temp.erase(0, 1);
    temp = temp + "AY";
    cout << temp << " ";
}

int main () {
    string userIn("I NEED THIS IN PIG LATIN");
    istringstream iss(userIn);

    string sub;
    while (iss >> sub)
        piglatin(sub);
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output you then get is:

```
IAY EEDNAY HISTAY NIAY IGPAY ATINLAY
```

which I don't think is *totally* correct Pig Latin (I seem to recall there were [slightly different rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) where words started with vowels, and you had to move consonant *groups* to the end rather than just the first one), but I'll leave you to fix that problem if necessary.

In terms of how the loop works:

```
while (iss >> sub)
    piglatin(sub);
```

This simply continues until the extraction of an item (word in this case) fails. Naive code (which I'll freely admit I've been guilty of) would use something like:

```
do { 
   string sub;
   iss >> sub;
   piglatin(sub);
} while (!iss.eof());
```

but that doesn't take into account the fact you may not *be* at the end of the file even when the extraction would fail, such as if your phrase had a space at the end, or if you were scanning integers when the next token in the stream was a non-integer.

---

And, just as an aside, there's no real need to do all those operations in `piglatin()` separately, nor is there a need for an (explicit) temporary string. You could replace the whole lot with:

```
void piglatin (string str) {
    cout << str.substr(1) + str.at(0) + "AY ";
}
```

It might be worthwhile *keeping* it as separate operations if you ever intend switching to "proper" Pig Latin since it's likely to be more complex, or if this is an assignment and you're not expected to be a C++ expert :-)

Comment: You were faster than me :)

Comment: Yeah the original pig latin problem has different rules but our professor gave us different rules to make it a little easy for us so he said take the first letter and put it at the end and then add ay to the end of the word and do this to every single word in the sentence the user enters.

Comment: @Koolkirtzz: okay, ignore that last bit. I'll leave it there for future people to see but, if your prof gave you a different definition, obviously that's the one you should use.

Comment: `istream::eof()` shouldn't be used as a loop condition; instead test for the extraction to fail. As written you may get an extra bogus call to `piglatin` after all the input words have been read. (Which would cause the exception to be thrown because it does `at(0)`)

Comment: @Matt, okay, I see what you're getting at. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I would suggest changing the loop to `for (string sub; iss >> sub; ) { piglatin(sub); }` .  You can test by putting a space on the end of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

... and because of the bug mentioned in the first answer, your code ends up making a call to piglatin() passing an empty string.

At that point, str.at(0) results in obvious undefined behavior (there is no character #0 in a completely empty string), which throws the runtime exception that you're complaining about.

Comment: `str.at(0)` does not cause undefined behaviour; it's defined to throw an exception.